# Does c# runtime cache typeof values for built-in types?

Tags: c#

Consider `typeof` calls for built-in types, e.g.:

```
if (myType == typeof(int) || myType == typeof(long)) { //...
```

Are those `typeof` calls evaluated every time, or does the runtime have a cache for such things?

One could have `static` variables for such values to guarantee the evaluation happens only once, but I'm curious whether the runtime does that already.

Comment: i would just use the typeof(long).MetadataToken and assign it to a readonly static field so that the comparisson does not have to figure it out every time.

Comment: They are certainly not cached at compile time. `typeof` expressions are not constant expressions. I don't know what happens at runtime though. The jitter could probably do something about this.

Comment: maybe can use Generic type to avoid it . but maybe need change your design .

Comment: Can you post more code , to know how to change your code.

Comment: @TimChang It's more of a theoretical question, I'd like to know what the runtime does.

Comment: OK I got it. 
https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/type.cs 
maybe you can see type source code. I thank it's not cache.

Comment: typeof will use ldtoken, its not a huge deal for the cli, however, the bigger concern is that you need to do this so much, which would be a larger architectural problem

Comment: AFAIK `Type` objects are cached internally. Bear in mind that `typeof(someType) is typeof(someType)` is true

Comment: Nothing to optimise (except possibly design?)...  `typeof()` is resolved at compile time and the "value" returned is the `System.Type`.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#typeof-operator.

Comment: If you are concerned about performance this should be a simple thing to test. I would expect that storing it in a static variable will make little or no difference, but it is risky to make assumptions about performance.